# When saving webpages, firefox sometimes does not open the previous directory

Tags: firefox

I sometimes download webpages when browsing them in Firefox, by hitting Ctrl-S.

I used to be able to save to the same folder as the folder to which I saved a webpage to last time, just by default.

But since a few months ago, this has been changed. When saving, the directory opened by default is often not the one that I saved to last time.

I wonder why? Is it on purpose, or a bug? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Firefox Support](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/887248?page=2#answer-324109).

To open the `about:config` page, type `about:config` in the location (address) bar and press the "Enter" key, just like you type the url of a website to open a website.

`about:config`

If you see a warning then you can confirm that you want to access the `about:config` page.
You have to **create a new Boolean pref via the right-click context menu** with the name **`browser.download.lastDir.savePerSite`** and set the value to false.

Use the Search (Filter) bar at the top of the `about:config` page to locate preferences more easily.

Preferences that have been modified show as bold (user set).

Preferences can be reset to the default via the right-click context menu if they are user set

Preferences can be changed via the right-click context menu: Modify (String or Integer) or Toggle (Boolean) or by double-clicking the line with the pref

`browser.download.lastDir.savePerSite` controls whether the directory preselected in the file picker for saving a file download is being remembered on a per-website (host) base. If set to true, the data is stored as [content preference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_content_preferences).

```
Type: boolean
Default value: true
Exists by default: no
Application support: Firefox 11.0
Status: Active; last updated 2012-02-15
Introduction: Pushed to Nightly on 2011-12-11
```

Bugs: [bug 702748](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=702748)

**Values**

*true* (default)

The last used directory for the website (host) serving the file for download will be preselected in the file picker. If no download directory for the current website has been stored, `browser.download.lastDir` will be used.

*false*

The last used directory for any download (stored in `browser.download.lastDir`) will be the preselected directory in the file picker.

Comment: Thanks! (1) Does setting true for `browser.download.lastDir.savePerSite` mean same directory for same site by default? What does it mean if I set it to be false? (2) I just checked. I don't have that option, instead I have `browser.download.lastDir`, which shows my last directory for download destination. I guess it changes as I change the destination of downloading, but it doesn't work properly, as I mentioned in my post.

Comment: @Tim read this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Preferences/browser.download.lastDir.savePerSite) from mozilla dev.

Comment: I have edited my comments.

Comment: You have to create it, it is not there. I have mentioned it in answer.

Comment: @Tim updated the answer you can check it now.